# Where does "this" point to in parent class (c++)?

Tags: c++, this

I have one question about C++ programming. If I have two classes called parent and child respectively. The child is derived from the parent. When I create an object either on the stack or the heap, it has to be initialized by the constructors of both classes. I find that the "this" ptrs are pointing to different addresss if you step into the constructor function while debugging. The "this" of the child class is pointing to the object, but what is the parent's "this" pointing to?

Here is my code for reference. FYI: I use g++ 10.3 and gdb 9.2 on Ubuntu 20.04

```
#include <iostream>

class parent
{
public:
    int attribute0, attribute1, attribute2, attribute3;
    parent():attribute0(0), attribute1(1), attribute2(2), attribute3(3){}
};
class child : parent
{
public:
    int attribute4;
    child(int arg) : parent() {
        attribute4 = arg;
    }
};

int main(){
    auto obj0 = new child(100);
    delete obj0;

    child obj1(80);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Strange side note: Inheritance implies [an is-a relationship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a) between base and derived. derived is-a base. This makes a parent-child relationship goofy because if `child` is derived from `parent` then `child` is a `parent`, and that makes no sense.

Comment: How do you think parents are made?

Comment: With a constructor.

Comment: Not that there's any hard requirements that it be this way, but gcc definitely seems to be using the same address in both: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/j6xqvohaf

Comment: It might be an interesting experiment to add the line `parent * ptr = obj0;` between the two existing lines that use `obj0`. How does the value of `ptr` compare to the values of the `this` pointer that you observed in the constructors?

Comment: There's an old book, "Inside the C++ Object Model" by Lippman, that has a very good treatment of how C++ objects are commonly laid out and how `this` pointers are handled.  Since it's an old book, the current compiler state of the art has likely changed a lot in terms of the details, but I'd guess much of the book is still relevant as far as fundamentals go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` always points to the beginning of the instance of whatever type it (`this`) is.

That probably sounds confusing, so let's try to visualize it. Now what I'm about to describe isn't part of the C++ standard, and every implementation is free to change it as they wish or need, but it's generally some form of this:

```
-----------------------------------------------------
| pre-parent | parent data | pre-child | child data |
-----------------------------------------------------
```

Inside `parent::parent()`, `this` is of type `const parent *` and so points to the beginning of the parent data. However inside `child::child()`, `this` is of type `const child *` and so points to the beginning of the child data. You can ignore the pre-parent and pre-child portions, those are implementation defined chunks of memory that describe the allocation, virtual table, debug sentries, etc.

So now it should be obvious why you can access the entire object through the parent's `this` (since all the child data is after it and thus accessible through regular member access), but you can't access the entire object through the child `this` without first casting it up to the full object.

It should also be obvious why the two `this` pointers don't point to the same address (though they could if the parent had no fields and the compiler didn't insert any pre-child data, so no debug mode).

Comment: One quick note, if the two pointers are the same, then your compiler is storing the child and parent reversed, ie the child first, followed by the parent. In that case to see the different pointers you can use multiple inheritance, because the compiler has no choice but to put at least one of the `this` pointers in a different location from the others.

Comment: It's a lot simpler than that. In single inheritance, most compilers treat the parent as the first member of the child, so the addresses tend to always line up, no matter what members each of the class have. Differentiated `this` tends to only occur when multiple inheritance is involved.

Comment: @Frank Except when the class has virtual functions in which case language implementations typically store a virtual pointer before the bases, and thus different addresses.

Comment: @eerorika That's only if the parent doesn't have a vtable in the first place, but yes. https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Gb9q5Mzd9

Comment: "you can't access the entire object through the child this without first casting it up to the full object".  There is no need to "cast up" to access public members of the parent.  However, if you have a parent `this` pointer, it must be down cast to a child type `this` pointer to access child members.  The downcast operation is only valid when the parent `this` is pointing to an object that is truly a child object.

Answer (score 5):

> Where does “this” point to in parent class (c++)?

In all member functions, `this` always points to the object whose member function is being called. This is regardless of type hierarchies. Within member function of a base, `this` points to the base sub object.

Answer (score 3):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
class parent
{
public:
    int attribute0, attribute1, attribute2, attribute3;
    parent():attribute0(0), attribute1(1), attribute2(2), attribute3(3){}
};
class child : parent
{
public:
    int attribute4;
    child(int arg) : parent() {
        attribute4 = arg;
    }
};

int main(){
    std::cout << "attribute0: " << offsetof(parent, attribute0) << "\n";
    std::cout << "attribute1: " << offsetof(parent, attribute1) << "\n";
    std::cout << "attribute2: " << offsetof(parent, attribute2) << "\n";
    std::cout << "attribute3: " << offsetof(parent, attribute3) << "\n";
    std::cout << "attribute4: " << offsetof(child, attribute4) << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

If you really want to know how the data is packaged, you can use offsetof on the member variables to see how your compiler is doing it *(it may give you some warnings though, so it's not a reliable way to use offsetof, but for educational purposes this is fine)*. https://godbolt.org/z/6dGxT9e6b

```cpp
attribute0: 0
attribute1: 4
attribute2: 8
attribute3: 12
attribute4: 16
```

'this' points to the start of the object in memory *(in this case, the same location as attribute0)*.

If you add a virtual method to the parent class, e.g.

```cpp
class parent
{
public:
    int attribute0, attribute1, attribute2, attribute3;
    parent():attribute0(0), attribute1(1), attribute2(2), attribute3(3){}
    virtual void func() {}
};
```

Then you will notice an extra 8bytes at the start:

```cpp
attribute0: 8
attribute1: 12
attribute2: 16
attribute3: 20
attribute4: 24
```

This 8bytes is to store the pointer to the vtable *(for 32bit code, this might be a 4byte offset)*

If you really want to see that 'this' is the same for both parent & child classes, just print out the value and take a look:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
class parent
{
public:
    int attribute0, attribute1, attribute2, attribute3;
    parent():attribute0(0), attribute1(1), attribute2(2), attribute3(3){}
    void printParent() {
        std::cout << "parent " << this << ' ' << &attribute0 << "\n";
    }
};
class child : public parent
{
public:
    int attribute4;
    child(int arg) : parent() {
        attribute4 = arg;
    }
    void printChild() {
        std::cout << "child  " << this << ' ' << &attribute4 << "\n";
    }
};

int main(){
    child* c = new child(4);
    c->printParent();
    c->printChild();
    return 0;
}
```

Prints:

```
parent 0x1f98eb0 0x1f98eb0
child  0x1f98eb0 0x1f98ec0
```

So, 'this' of the parent, 'this' of the child, and attribute0, all point to the same memory location. The address of attribute4 is exactly 16bytes after 'this', which is what offsetof told us earlier.